# error in Flutter The named parameter 'onChanged' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. Try adding the required argument

Tags: flutter, syntax-error

What is the problem? How can I solve it? My codes:

[image]

Comment: Please avoid sharing code through images. Instead, use a website like pastebin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you must initialize onChanged or remove onChange required from your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the onChanged argument in ApprovalQueuePage as it is required.Pass it like this:

```
//When calling approval queue leave everything as it is
//just replace ApprovalQueuePage() with
ApprovalQueuePage(onChanged: (String value){
    //You can do anything with the value
})
```

Comment: error The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)'

Comment: @AbdulAzizPermana, the function you have to pass must take a String as its parameter. So here instead of onChanged: (){} you should use onChanged:(String value){}. I shall change my code above and see that for complete answer.